# Binding Panorama Items in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have two panorama pages. The first one contains letters, the second one contains verbs that start with that letter. When user tap on the a letter, the app should redirect them to the second page with verbs. I got the HeaderItem of the Panorama to work, but not the list of the verbs. It just empty.

Here is the event on the first page:

```
// Navigate to the second page:
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Verbs.xaml?selectedItem=" + (alphabet.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).ID, UriKind.Relative));
```

On the second page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
            {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];            
            }
        }
    }
```

The XAML file of the second page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="Verb">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <!--Binding LineOne works!-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding LineOne}">                
            <ListBox x:Name="verblist" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--But this one does not work-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Verb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Search">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Can you show me the problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add items to the listbox,

```
 <ListBox x:Name="verblist" Margin="0,0,-12,0" Items={Binding YOUR_ITEMS_LOCATION_HERE}>
```

or by code:

```
verblist.Items = xxxx;
```